# ActiveRecord PendingMigrationError railstutorial chapter 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

when I try to see my `users/1` view in sample_app in browser in chapter 7 in https://www.railstutorial.org/book and that what I get:

[image]

I make sure that all code writing/copy in right way. so what i can do about it?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the error message, run `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development` to run the pending migrations.

Before you do that, you can check that there are pending migrations by running `rake db:migrate:status RAILS_ENV=development`; it will show that there are some migrations with status `down`. Once you apply the pending migrations, all migrations will have status `up`.

Comment: Thanks for helping me... but after i run that i get error: 
add_column(:users, :password_digest, :string)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: password_digest: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD "password_digest" varchar/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:333:in `block in execute'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:466:in `block in log'
..

Comment: Please start from Chapter 1 of the book you are reading to understand what you are doing.